# serverless step functions: Getting error when passing more than one fields in the payload for lambda

Tags: aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

Error: `Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: The value for the field 'Date.$' must be a valid JSONPath at /States/Insert Data Dynamodb/Parameters' (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDefinition;`

below is the corresponding serverless.yaml code.

I tried wrapping the two parameters into encoded json string and passed it as single payload field and it resulted in the same error but when there is only one plain field in the payload this code deployed successfully

Any suggestions on how to pass two parameters?

```
service: service-name

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
region: us-east-1
  tags: ${self:custom.tagsObject}
  logRetentionInDays: 1
  timeout: 10
  deploymentBucket: lambda-repository
  memorySize: 128
  tracing:
    lambda: true

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions

configValidationMode: error

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    sortData:
      name: datasorting-dev
      type: STANDARD
      role: ${self:custom.datasorting.${self:provider.stage}.iam}
      definition:
        Comment: "Data Sort"
        StartAt: Query Data
        States:
          Query Data:
            Type: Task
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync
            Parameters:
              QueryString: >-
               select * from table.data 
              WorkGroup: primary
              ResultConfiguration:
                OutputLocation: s3://output/location
            Next: Insert Data Dynamodb
          Insert Data Dynamodb: 
            Type: Task
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke
            Parameters: 
              FunctionName: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${account-id}:function:name
              Payload: 
                OutputLocation.$: $.QueryExecution.ResultConfiguration.OutputLocation
                Date.$: ${self:custom.dates.year}${self:custom.dates.month}${self:custom.dates.day}
            End: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Date.$` property has value of `${self:custom.dates.year}${self:custom.dates.month}${self:custom.dates.day}`. Let's assume that:

```
const dates = {
  "year": "2000",
  "month": "01",
  "day": "20"
}
```

The result will be `Date.$: "20000120"` which is not a valid JSON Path.

JSON Path needs to start with a `$` sign and each level is divided by `.`.

Do you want to achieve something like this? `$.2000.01.20`?

As you see, the issue is not with passing 2 parameters but with wrong string JSON Path created by string interpolation for `Date.$`.

Some useful links:

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html